# Two different ways of class inheritance and what's the difference?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class person and a subclass teacher:

```
class Person:
    species="human"
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname=fname
        self.lastname=lname

person_1=Person("Mike", "Smithfield")
person_2=Person("Sara", "Smithfield")

print(person_1.species)
print(person_1.firstname)
print(person_1.lastname)

class Teacher(Person):
    typeof="School teacher"
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, schoolgrade):
        Person.__init__(self, fname, lname)
        self.schoolclass=schoolgrade

teacher_1=Teacher("John", "Dire", "first grade")

print(teacher_1.species)
print(teacher_1.typeof)
print(teacher_1.firstname)
print(teacher_1.lastname)
print(teacher_1.schoolclass)
```

With `class Teacher(Person):` Teacher is a subclass of person. So it inherits everyting from the class person. However, as I use `def __init__(self, fname, lname, schoolgrade):` the `__init__()` function overrides inheritance of the parent's `__init__()` function, therefore I have to add a `Person.__init__(self, fname, lname)`.

Now I wondered, if I could do instead the following:
I just use a `class Teacher(Person):` statement. No `__init__()` and therefore the inheritance behaviour is kept. Then I add an additional method to this subclass. In all it looks like:

```
class Person:
    species="human"
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname=fname
        self.lastname=lname

person_1=Person("Mike", "Smithfield")
person_2=Person("Sara", "Smithfield")

print(person_1.species)
print(person_1.firstname)
print(person_1.lastname)

class Teacher(Person):
    typeoft="School teacher"
    def schoolspec(self, schoolgrade):
        self.schoolclass=schoolgrade


teacher_1=Teacher("James", "Orland")

print(teacher_1.species)
print(teacher_1.typeoft)
print(teacher_1.firstname)
print(teacher_1.lastname)

teacher_1.schoolspec("Grade 1")
print(teacher_1.schoolclass)
```

From my point of view, it leads to the same result. I have a teacher with instance attribute schoolclass equal to first grade. I do not understand the difference between these two approaches and I am not understanding why I should do the first way, as it looks more complicated to me.

**Question 1:**

Where is the difference between these two approaches?

**Question 2:**

What is the advantage/disadvantage of each?

Comment: It doesn't lead to the same result, because now every time you create a `Teacher` object you have to call the `schoolspec` method.

Comment: There are schools of thought that say that every object should be created complete at the point of creation. Your first method does this. If for some reason you have to use the second method, you can always wrap `Teacher` creation inside a factory function which guarantees to perform the two steps for you.

Comment: The first method *enforces* the setting of the `schoolclass` attribute while the second method allows for the possibility of it being undefined. Not so good that.